# Webkit: contextmenu / click handling bug workaround?

Tags: javascript, events, webkit, cross-browser, contextmenu

I'm trying to work with the contextmenu & click handlers on an anchor element in a cross-browser way, and it's proving really difficult.

Here's the problem: if `preventDefault()` is called on a contextmenu event from a contextmenu event handler, browsers behave differently.  All browsers correctly do not display their browser's default context menu.  In Chrome & Safari, however, the browser then follows a click event for the element (and only if the contextmenu event is canceled).

When I cancel a contextmenu event from a contextmenu handler, I do NOT want a successive click event fired on the same element.   Is there a clean way to resolve this?  Neither returning false on the contextmenu handler nor the calling stopPropagation function alleviate the issue!

[Here](http://jsbin.com/eburuj/6/edit) is a demo with a strange glitch (use Webkit inspector or Firebug to see the trace)

---

Here's one answer: use jQuery rather than POJ to cleanup width/height stuff:

```
    function Cancel_Next_Click()
    {
        // Compatibility - Chrome & Safari bug where context click event is followed by an undesired click event

        var Cancel_Next_Click_Element = document.createElement("div");
        Cancel_Next_Click_Element.style.position = "fixed";
        Cancel_Next_Click_Element.style.left = "0px";
        Cancel_Next_Click_Element.style.top = "0px";
        Cancel_Next_Click_Element.style.width = window.innerWidth;
        Cancel_Next_Click_Element.style.height =window.innerHeight;
        document.body.appendChild(Cancel_Next_Click_Element);

        var Cancel_Next_Click_Element_Listener = function() {
                document.body.removeChild(Cancel_Next_Click_Element);
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', Cancel_Next_Click_Element_Listener, false);
            }

        document.addEventListener('mouseup', Cancel_Next_Click_Element_Listener, false);
    }
```

Comment: do you **have** to use POJ? or could you use jquery or some other framework? at that you might be able to use something other then an `a` tag to accomplish this

Comment: If jquery or any other framework does resolve this problem, I'd be really interested in knowing! I tried binding events in jQuery in every deprecated and new way it offers, but they all do not resolve what I consider a WebKit bug.

Comment: Currently, the cleanest and most universal way to resolve this might be to create an ephemeral intercepting element in the context menu handler that nullifies the click, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 1):

by using some other element like a `span` for instance you wouldn't have to worry about the default action, since there wouldn't be a click even by default. I found these two jquery plugins that might do the trick for you:

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

http://beckelman.net/post/2008/11/04/Right-or-Left-Click-Context-Menu-Using-jQuery-Demo.aspx

Comment: Thanks! - 1) jquery context menu plugin actually doesn't display a context menu at all in Chrome. (Works in Firefox!)

Comment: 2) right-or-left-click-context-menu demo doesn't work in Chrome/Safari either! (Works in Firefox!)

Comment: In the case that you do need an href, for example, to display the url in the browser status bar, and to have cross-browser-and-robot compatibility, etc, you have no choice but to use an anchor tag. this is tough!

Comment: I just tried both of their demo pages in Chrome and IE9 and both worked fine for me

Comment: Eonasdan, this may be a Mac bug!